# Woocommerce - clickable catalog thumbnails and gallery display

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I make product thumbnails in related products and shop (catalog) page click through to the single product? It had an add to cart wrapper that was removed and now it just hovers.

http://www.woodcabinetsite.com/product-category/kitchen-cabinets/

Also, each single product displays its thumbnails in a gallery format (where they're all stacked) - I'd like to figure out how to get those thumbnails to display in a carousel format, since each product has 5-10 gallery images.

http://www.woodcabinetsite.com/product/vanilla-maple/

I've tried looking into the product-thumbnails.php but can't figure this out.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried and that is not working

Comment: Separate questions should be, well, separate questions.

Comment: @Kirby - I'm not sure what file I should be editing to make the thumbnails clickable in catalog and related product display.

Comment: WooCommerce does this by default, so your theme has already modified `content-product.php`. You can start with disabling that template by renaming it to anything else, ex: `content-product.bak` so that WooCommerce will use it's default.

Comment: @helgatheviking - Thank you for your reply, but that didn't work (for either)... Where else do you think it could be?

Comment: I'm only dealing with the first question concerning links. Again please move the second question to its own question. I don't know if you've done this live, but I'm not seeing any change to your site. The source markup should read `<li class="product"><a href="PERMALINK"><img></a></li>` or thereabouts. The image and title are all wrapped in a permalink to the single product. Since it *doesn't* I am 98% certain that you are still overriding `content-product.php`. You could also verify that in your WooCommerce settings.

Answer (score -1):

If you are still looking for the answer, just find your `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>` tag in your theme's content-product.php file. Edit the file to make sure this tag is before the first `<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>` and is closed after this `<li>` tag is closed. This modification will make the entire product clickable.